# My C# console app is not running the correct calculations

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a piece of code that converts given input to degrees Fahrenheit.

The formula I am trying to apply is Temperature (so whatever the user inputs) * 1.8 + 32. However it gives back a wrong output (68 where it should be 64 if I recall correctly).

I tried just about everything: converting, supplying a type in the calculation itself, but nothing helped.

If anyone knows how I can make it output the proper value please inform me.

```
int Temperature = 18;
Console.Write("Input the temperature in degrees Celcius. \n");
Temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The temperature is " + Temperature + "°C");
int TempFahrenheit = Temperature * Convert.ToInt32(1.8) + 32;
Console.WriteLine("Converted to degrees Fahrenheit this is " + TempFahrenheit + "°F");
```

Comment: guess what `Convert.ToInt32(1.8)` returns, and what are implications of this...

Comment: It returns 2. oh so it rounds up. But what is the fix so I can use the number as it is supposed to be used. I am using a formula as I stated so I need it as is but it doesn't accept floats/doubles and ints to be used, hence one of the two has to be converted. I picked the decimal number.

Comment: I duno ... maybe you wana use it with results of multiplication

Comment: Try this: int TempFahrenheit = (int)(Temperature * 1.8f + 32f);

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds can you submit your answer as a comment so I can give you the proper reputation points? if any. It worked. I completely forgot about being able to assign stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 int TempFahrenheit = (int)(Temperature * 1.8f + 32f);
```

The line Convert.ToInt32(1.8) will result in a whole number, which will make the calculation incorrect. You need to do the calculation first, then if you need to convert the result to an integer.
It may be better to store the result as a float for more precision:

```
float TempFahrenheit =  Temperature * 1.8f + 32f;
```

Then when you want to display it you can do this just to display the integer part:

```
string displayTemp = TempFahrenheit.ToString("0")
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why using integers and integer multiplication won't work!

Answer (score 0):

An integer is a whole number, so if you make an int which is 1.8, that will make it 1 actually *(apparently 2, with Convert.ToInt32(1.8))*. Integers always get rounded down.
If you want to declare 1.8 as a different datatype. you could use 1.8f for a float, 1.8d for a double, or 1.8m for a decimal.

```
int Temperature = 18;
Console.Write("Input the temperature in degrees Celcius. \n");
Temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The temperature is " + Temperature + "°C");
//changed 1.8 to double
int TempFahrenheit = Temperature * 1.8d + 32;
Console.WriteLine("Converted to degrees Fahrenheit this is " + TempFahrenheit + "°F");
```

[image: creating non-whole numbers]

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Note: float is less precise than a double, which is less precise than a decimal. In most cases, a double or float will be fine, also for your use case.

Comment: Why did you post the "Real literals" overview as image? This is not useful. It is text.

Comment: It shows how you can declare a variable as a double, like i did in "int TempFahrenheit = Temperature * 1.8d + 32;". It was a change I made to the code, and it's easier to have this information right under the code, than to just add a link. Providing the source of information you're supplying is very useful, you know?

Comment: Yes, but you should not post it as image, but as text

Comment: I did in my own words, above the code. What does it matter? There's a bunch of formatting in the text. If you wanna edit the post so that it has the same formatting, be my guest.